# Unable to assign group permissions with ICACLS on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, file-permissions, windows-authentication, icacls

I cannot get icacls to accept my group for adding permissions.  I am using an elevated power shell with the following command:

```
icacls 'C:/foo' /grant:r 'Group Foo':f
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid parameter "Group Foo"
```

I have tried using the SUID too, but that fails as well.  I have also tried 'Domain\Group Foo'

I have a bunch of files I am trying to allow a group to use.  What is the proper way to add mass permissions in Windows Server 2012?

-- EDIT --

```
E:\> icacls "E:/Contact Numbers.xlsx" /grant:r "Users":f
Invalid parameter "Users"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
C:\>mkdir foo

C:\>icacls 'C:/foo' /grant:r 'Users':f
'Users': No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

C:\>icacls "C:/foo" /grant:r "Users":f
processed file: C:/foo
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

I missed that you were using Powershell, not `cmd`.  Powershell has some high weirdness when mixing external commands and quoting.  Here's a couple examples using Powershell.

PS v2:  To pass the quotes onto `icacls` you must escape them with a caret.  Note parenthesis around the "F" need escaped as well.

```
PS C:\>icacls `"C:/foo`" /grant:r `"Users`":`(F`)
```

PS v3: Version 3 offers a new escape sequence `--%` (dash, dash, percent) which escapes the remainder of the line. This makes even complex external parameters simple.

```
PS C:\>icacls --% "C:/foo" /grant:r "Users":F
```

Comment: See my edit above.  This did not work either.  Note that I am getting "Invalid parameter" errors and not "No mapping between account names"

Comment: I just tried again using command prompt instead of power shell and it worked.  Don't know what the issue is there but thanks for the correct syntax.

Comment: Sorry, totally skipped over that you were using PS. Updated to include PS 2/3 examples.

Comment: To the people complaining it doesnt work, you have to use the command in Command Prompt. The command does not work in powershell.

Answer (score 3):

It won't let me comment on jscott's thread but in order to make your command run properly in Powershell, you'll have to add quotes around the entire parameter, as such:

```
    C:\> icacls .\foo /grant:r "Users:F"
```

This will work for group names that have spaces in them, as well as commands including inherit permissions.

```
    C:\> icacls .\foo /grant:r "Remote Desktop Users:(OI)(CI)(F)"
```

When in doubt, always apply quotes around the full parameter. Hope this helps! :)